# I have problem working with sys-person entity.It is not recognizing non-english names like Hema , Kishan

Tags: watson-conversation

sys-person entity is not recognizing all the names.for ex- Hema, Laxman are not recognized but names like John,Michael are easily recognized.

How to fix this problem

Comment: What code are you using? What have you tried? It is hard to help with this little information

Comment: @RAB I created a slot which ask user about user-name and used **sys-person** entity to identify the names.But in the **"try it out"** panel, while entering some Indian or non-english names  which I have mentioned above the **sys-person** entity is not able to grab the names.While for English names like:- John, Michael etc it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you cannot extend `@sys-person` or any of the other system entities.

The only real method here is to also have your own entity list. I have a list called `@names` into which I add extra names that are not in sys-person. This also includes names that are the lowercase version of names that sys-person also does not capture ( although it does capture the same name which starts with an uppercase letter ). I have a Bug logged with the development team for additions to the names in sys-person due to this issue.

> You then have to just add `@names` into your node conditions the same
>   as you would sys-person.
>   . (@names || @sys-person)

[source](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/414493/system-entity-customization/)